Find the coordinates of a point in a rectangle
Given a rectangle ABCD with sides 5 and 15. Let's assume that rectangle vertics have coordinates A(0,0) B(0,5) C(15,5) D(15,0). Point P inside rectangle is connected to the vertices of the rectangle by straight segments, with the angle between segments AP and DP equal to 150°, and the angle between segments DP and CP equal to 45°. How to find the coordinates of a point P?


Please show your approach and use MathJax.

This is a general idea, I'll leave it up to you to complete the solution. Let the sides of the triangles that have $P$ as a vertex be $x, y, z$. The following system of non-linear equations will allow you to determine $x, y, z$:
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2-2xy\cos 150^\circ=225  \\
y^2+z^2-2yz\cos 45^\circ=25 \\
x^2+z^2-2xz\cos 165^\circ=250
\end{cases}
$$
Once you obtained $x, y, z$, the problem becomes trivial.

Perfect solution!
